# Access data in a pointed-to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Yeah I know that that may seems a strange and complicated title but Here is a situtaion , I have a class named terrain that stores and make actions on a square terrain of Tiles, who are classes , the terrain is stored in a two dimensionnal array (for being grid) , and I have a member whose purpose is assign a Tile to a Coordinate , which is a cell in the vector , but when tring to do so , the compiler gives me a long error with the operator= :

```
||=== Build: Debug in TilesWar (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\qbsec_000\Traxys\Documents\Cpp\Programms\TilesWar\terrain.cpp||In member function 'void Terrain::setTileFromCoord(Coord, Tile)':|
C:\Users\qbsec_000\Traxys\Documents\Cpp\Programms\TilesWar\terrain.cpp|15|error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<Tile> > >::value_type {aka std::vector<Tile>}' and 'Tile')|
C:\Users\qbsec_000\Traxys\Documents\Cpp\Programms\TilesWar\terrain.cpp|15|note: candidates are:|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc|160|note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Tile; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tile>]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc|160|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Tile' to 'const std::vector<Tile>&'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|439|note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = Tile; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tile>]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|439|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Tile' to 'std::vector<Tile>&&'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|461|note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = Tile; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tile>]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|461|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Tile' to 'std::initializer_list<Tile>'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Here is some of the code related to it :

```
#ifndef TERRAINN_H_INCLUDED
#define TERRAINN_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include "Tile.h"

typedef struct Coord Coord;
struct Coord{
    int x;
    int y;
};
class Terrain{
public:
    Terrain();
    Terrain(int tSize);
    Terrain(int terrainSize,/*std::string terainTheme,*/int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3,int x4,int y4); //TODO: Compress the coordonates
    bool isTileClear(int x,int y); //TODo: COmpress the coord
    bool getTexture(int x, int y);//TODO: Compress the coord
    void setTileFromCoord(Coord point, Tile tile);
    void setSpawnPoint(Coord point);

private:
    std::vector< std::vector <Tile> > *terrain;
    //std::string terrainTheme; //Unused with the fact that texture are not designated by the terrain but by the XML file
    int terrainSize;    //This is mentionned in the [Map].xml file
};

#endif // TERRAINN_H_INCLUDED
```

---

```
#ifndef TILE_H_INCLUDED
#define TILE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class TileModel{
public:
    TileModel();
    TileModel(bool tileType, std::string texturePath); //Created by using XMLHandling
    bool getTileType(); //Return the clear(false) or notClear(true)
    std::string getTexturePath();
private:
    bool tileType;
    std::string texturePath;
};

class Tile{
public:
    Tile();
    Tile(TileModel* model);
    TileModel getModel();
private:
    TileModel* model;
};

#endif // TILE_H_INCLUDED
```

---

```
Terrain::Terrain(int tSize){
    terrain = new vector<vector<Tile>>(tSize,vector<Tile>(tSize));
}

void Terrain::setTileFromCoord(Coord point,Tile tile){
    terrain[5][10] = tile;
}

Tile::Tile(TileModel *model) : model(model){

}
Tile::Tile() : model(0){
    model = new TileModel(false,"Data/Texture/debugPath.png");
}
```

I can't Understand that much ther errror(I have just started messing up with the STL and vectors) so can someone explain me the errror , and maybe give me a fix , or a hint to it , Thanks !

PS Some of the code is WIP, and will surely be changed

Thanks to The One I have my answer who was remonving the pointer, thanks !

Comment: you need pointer to vector, or vector of pointers? Also you could show us the line where the error is reported?

Comment: Please post your code/error messages here, do **not** link to them. Links might become invalid in the future, and questions on SO should remain useful in the future.

Comment: Your error says: "In member function 'void Terrain::setTileFromCoord(Coord, Tile)" but your are **not** showing this code. Please add the member function definition to your question.

Comment: @Traxys just accept the answer - don't edit your post to edit in the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to assign Tile into a pointer that points at vector, instead of vector itself. You either change the line in `Terrain::setTileFromCoord` to `terrain->operator[](5)[10] =tile;`, or as your code seems to be, drop the aestrik(*) from the definition of the `std::vector< std::vector <Tile> > *terrain;`, because this makes your variable a pointer to vector of vectors of Tiles. Vector doesnt need to be pointed to in most cases.

Comment: The pointer was just for the fact that I did not really Know how to make the constructor tSize in another way (actually I did not test anything else because before the vector there was a basic array that strangely did not work , but thanks :D